# Dot net mvc application hosted on Azure suddenly redirects to login page again and again until restarted

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-webapps

I have 2 `Dot net mvc5` applications. A frontend and an API application hosted on `Azure`as Webapps. The frontend application has `Azure AD` authentication setup in code. Here is the code below from `startup.auth.cs` file

```
        var authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantID"]);
        var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .Build();

        var signedInUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity);
        var tokenStore = new SessionTokenStore(idClient.UserTokenCache, HttpContext.Current, signedInUser);

        try
        {
            string[] scopes = graphScopes.Split(' ');

            var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();

            var userDetails = await GraphHelper.GetUserDetailsAsync(result.AccessToken);

            var cachedUser = new CachedUser()
            {
                DisplayName = userDetails.DisplayName,
                Email = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userDetails.Mail) ?
                userDetails.UserPrincipalName : userDetails.Mail,
                Avatar = string.Empty,
                AccessToken=result.AccessToken
            };
            MethodHelper methodHelper = new MethodHelper();
            Dictionary<string, dynamic> authOutput = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
            authOutput =await methodHelper.AuthorizeUserByEmailID(cachedUser.Email);
            if (authOutput["Success"])
            {
                AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUserDetails = authOutput["AuthenticatedUser"];
                if (authenticatedUserDetails != null&& authenticatedUserDetails.HasToolAccess)
                {
                    AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser = new AuthenticatedUser();
                    authenticatedUser = authOutput["AuthenticatedUser"];
                    cachedUser.UserID = authenticatedUser.UserId;
                    cachedUser.UserEmpId = authenticatedUser.UserEmpId;
                    cachedUser.DepartmentId = authenticatedUser.DepartmentId;
                    cachedUser.Department = authenticatedUser.Department;
                    tokenStore.SaveUserDetails(cachedUser);
                }
                else
                {
                
                    string message = "User Details return null";
                    notification.HandleResponse();
                    notification.Response.Redirect($"/Home/Error?message={message}&debug={message}");
                } else
            {
                string message = authOutput["Exception"];
                notification.HandleResponse();
                notification.Response.Redirect($"/Home/Error?message={message}&debug={message}");
            }
```

Here once the `accesstoken` is successfully received by the application it calls the API login method to fetch other details of the user

```
authOutput =await methodHelper.AuthorizeUserByEmailID(cachedUser.Email);
```

performs this task.
This works completely fine when less number of users log into the system. But suddenly during the day. The application stops working and all the users are redirected to the login screen again and again. `Until the Web App is restarted`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Forms tag in your **web.config**, you might have given the **~/Login** url.

I have added the **LoginUrl** as **~/Login**  in my config file and observed the same issue , I have modified the redirection  to "~/Index" , it worked fine for me.

Change the form **LoginUrl** in your config to the existing Index route **"~/Index"** if you have or create a new Action to handle this route.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Index" name="AuthClientUser"
           timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" 
           path="/">
     </forms>
</authentication>
```

And add the following to the **appSettings** section in web.config

```cs
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

The authorization section of web.config denies all anonymous users.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Harshitha
Here is my cookie configuration code
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
                CookieManager = new SystemWebChunkingCookieManager(),
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn"),
                LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/SignOut"),
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2),
                SlidingExpiration = true,
         
            });

Comment: I tried the solution but unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Please check the  authorization section of web.config , that denies all anonymous users.